# How to merge pages of a pdf from the command line

Tags: files, pdf, pdftk

From a pdf of n pages, how to reduce by half the number of pages by merging several pages on a single page? Each pair of pages from the old pdf should be found side by side on the new pdf.

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you could show us a simple mock-up. Do you mean that you want each page of the new PDF to hold 2 pages of the old one? (Also, hey Remi, fancy meeting you here! :) )

Comment: Hey @terdon! yes, this is what I mean, each page of the new PDF should hold 2 pages of the old one (side by side)?

Comment: My question is indeed a duplicate. Thank you guys!

Comment: I just tested and the default options (`pdfnup input.pdf -o output.pdf`) seem to do exactly what you need.